# openjdk11 : Unsupported CipherSuite Exception

Tags: java, java-11, openjdk-11

My app is using [OpenJDK 11](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/) and fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported CipherSuite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.validValuesOf(CipherSuite.java:916)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:302)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure(RemoteTCPConnection.java:2084)
```

I am not sharing any code because I don't think the problem is there. I need to fix this exception somehow.

Is it possible to configure JRE to support this particular CipherSuite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally `TLS_RSA_...` not `SSL_RSA_...` in recent Java versions as SSLv3 is no longer secure.

IBM JRE might supports `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` cipher suite as per [Configuring your application to use IBM Java or Oracle Java CipherSuite mappings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031290_.htm) docs but this is not a valid constant in OpenJDK.

The `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` cipher suite was introduced in Java 7 as per [Java Cryptography Architecture Oracle Providers Documentation for JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) docs. Use this constant in OpenJDK.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. I did that but got another exception : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE') My app needs to connect to IBM MQ.

Comment: You should refer to MQ development guide. It should tell you if you can run a client with OpenJDK or do you need IBM JRE.

Comment: Lust leave it here: using this jvm option `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` helped me. So `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` + `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` works :)

Comment: After using this jvm.option (in my Liberty server root), I am now getting error *RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host '10.60.28.75(1418)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target],3=10.60.28.75/10.60.28.75:1418*